# Векторная графика в Android

Tags: android

Изучая разработку под Андройд, задался вопросом. При использовании android:src на API выше 19, будут ли картинки  использовать векторную графику?

Как я понял при API ниже 19, изображения будут растровыми (картинки разбиваются на несколько PNG) если использовать android:src.

Но если использовать app:srcCompat, то они уже будут векторными.

Подскажите, так ли это?

Comment: Лучше всего в 2019 году отказаться от поддержки API меньше 21. Проблем с этим тьма, а пользы почти никакой (мало юзеров). У меня есть успешный опыт уговаривания клиентов крупных на это. В итоге довольны все.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб согласен!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, понял. Просто для расширения кругозора решил разобраться в этом :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, надо использовать `app:srcCompat`. Советую изучить данную картинку, вместо тысячи слов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое.